# How to prevent my items from duplicating using Redux Toolkit + Strapi + React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx, reduce, strapi

My Items keep on duplicating on shopping cart and I cant seems to figure out. Hope to get some guidance here and would be a great help for my project!

Below are my code :

CartReducer.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  isCartOpen: false,
  cart: [],
  count: [],
  products: [],
};

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setProducts: (state, action) => {
      state.products = action.payload;
    },

    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.cart.find(
        (product) => product.id === action.payload.id
      );

      console.log(item);
      if (item) {
        item.count += action.payload.count;
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cart: [...state.cart, action.payload.product],
        };
      }
    },
```

Full Github repo : https://github.com/TheKelvinT/Teck-Hong-CS.git

I've tried looking up several sample projects and changing my code based on those but it still does not work.

Comment: It's better to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example instead of a git repo.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have there, that:

```
item.count += action.payload.count;
```

this line actually does nothing, because you don't use this down stream, to make it work that way you would need something like that:

```js
const itemIndex = state.cart.findIndex((product) => product.id === action.payload.id);

if (itemIndex !== -1) {
   state.cart[itemIndex] = {...state.cart[itemIndex], count: action.payload.count }
} else ...
```

Just a note that it is not obvious where you keep your count, the line above adds count to `item` `in` `the` `cart`.

There might be more issues with this code, hover i can recommend in terms of cart use state normalization technique [reference](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape). Although that it may look a bit strange, it is quite easy and powerful:

The first thing is to remove products from cart slice, with slices, it's really better to have them as flat as possible, it's much easier to extend after:
`/slices/products.js`

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const { actions, reducer } = createSlice({
  name: 'products',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
     setProducts: (state, {payload}) => payload,
  }
})

export const productsReducer = reducer;
export const { setProducts } = actions;
```

Cart slice, is going to have to main properties, the first one is `ids` an array of id's of products added to cart, the second one would be `products` it's so called `key` `value` `pair` with `key` is product id, value is an object with `product` property and `count` an integer for count:
`/slices/cart.js`

```js
import { createSelector, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const { actions, reducer } = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: {
    ids: [],
    products: {},
  },
  reducers: {
    // the payload is { product, count }
    addCart: (state, { payload }) => {
      if (!state.ids.includes(payload.product.id)) {
        state.ids.push(payload.product.id);
        state.products[payload.product.id] = { product: payload.product, count: payload.count };
      } else state.products[payload.product.id].count += payload.count;
      // you should always validate the count e.g. Math.max(0, payload.count)
    },
    // this would just remove from cart, you can do yourself count change
    removeCart: (state, { payload }) => {
      if (state.ids.includes(payload.product.id)) {
        state.ids = state.ids.filter((id) => id !== payload.product.id);
        delete state.products[payload.product.id];
      }
    },
  },
});

export const cartReducer = reducer;
export const { addCart, removeCart } = actions;

// BONUS, is selector that checks if object is in the cart
// const isInCart = useSelector((state) => isInCartSelector(state, id))
export const isInCartSelector = createSelector(
    (state, id) => state.cart,
    (state, id) => id,
    (cart, id) => cart.ids.includes(id)
);
```